# Use the Shellshock vulnerability to get a root console as a normal user

Tags: linux, shellshock

Owner is root and also made a Set-UID for the following code snippet:

```
# include <stdio .h>

void main () {
  setuid ( geteuid ());
  system ("/ bin/ls -l");
}
```

How might the Shellshock vulnerability be used to get a root console for the above program?

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

According to the manpage for system(), the system() function will execute the commands using `/bin/sh -c`. Shellshock is a vulnerability in [now] old versions of the Bash shell, and it is not applicable to sh.

However, if you were to do something like `system( /bin/bash <somecommand> )`, that may expose you to this vulnerability, depending whether or not the environment variables are forwarded to the Bash command within the system call. Hopefully someone else can chime in on this.